# Divergence (math operator) of matrix product with cdot -- how to control spacing?

Tags: spacing, math-operators

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{Div}

\begin{document}
I want to compute the divergence of the product $\boldsymbol F \cdot \boldsymbol C$, but the
code below looks like I want to compute $\Div(\boldsymbol F) \cdot \boldsymbol C$. 
Round brackets are not common in my field.` 

$\Div \boldsymbol F \cdot \boldsymbol C$

\end{document}
```

It is common in my field to define the matrix multiplication between two matrices $\boldsymbol F$ and $\boldsymbol C$ by \cdot.
\Div represents the divergence operator.

The output of the code looks like $\Div(\boldsymbol F) \cdot \boldsymbol C$. How can I make clear that I want to compute $\Div ( \boldsymbol F \cdot \boldsymbol C )$. I can not use round brackets.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a TeX-related question. However, since Div F is a scalar, multiplying it by C would not make sense.

Comment: As indicated in the title, I would like to control the spacing to the left and right of cdot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's better to use parentheses. Anyway, since the divergence operator yields a scalar, it would have no sense interpreting “Div F” multiplied by “C” rather than divergence of the matrix product C times F.

You can reduce the space around the dot (which is commonly *not* used for matrix products, though) as follows

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{Div}

\newcommand{\dcdot}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \nonscript\mspace{-\muexpr\medmuskip*2/3}%
    \cdot
    \nonscript\mspace{-\muexpr\medmuskip*2/3}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\Div \bm{F} \cdot \bm{C}$ (with \verb|\cdot|)

$\Div \bm{F} \dcdot \bm{C}$ (with \verb|\dcdot|)

$\scriptstyle \Div \bm{F}\dcdot \bm{C}$

\end{document}
```

Beware of never using `\dcdot` as a unary symbol. This reduces the space to one third of the standard.

[image]

Comment: Why did you add $\scriptstyle \Div \bm{F}\dcdot \bm{C}$ to your answer?

Comment: @Simon Just to check that the spacing doesn't get wrong in case `\dcdot` is used in a subscript.